# The difference between Subject Key Identifier and sha1Fingerprint in X509 Certificates

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509

I have some SW that extracts certificates data and the SW utilizes OpenSSL. I am confused what is the difference between the `subjectKeyIdentifier` and the `sha1Fingerprint`. Both are hash values. My intuition is that the `subjectKeyIdentifier` is the hash of the public-key of the certificate and the `sha1Fingerprint` is the hash of the overall fields of the certificate. This [reference](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO18140.html#SKI) says about the `subjectKeyIdentifier`:

> This is a hash value of the SSL certificate.

This is an example of what I get from the SW:

```
"subjectKeyIdentifier": "A8:XX:6A:XX:04:7D:DD:BA:E6:D1:XX:XX:XX:45:65:EF:F3:XX:EC:XX", "sha1Fingerprint": "E6:XX:XX:5B:06:XX:50:9B:XX:82:XX:2D:XX:6E:XX:97:XX:95:XX:CB"
```

Note: `XX` in the examples is used for redaction.

The question is: What is the difference between the two hashes? What each hash is for?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [subject key identifier (SKID)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.2.1.2) is an x509 extension and thus actually part of the certificate. The fingerprint instead is not part of the certificate but instead computed from the certificate. A certificate does not need to have an SKID at all and can have at most one SKID. But since the fingerprint is just a computed from the certificate there can be multiple fingerprints, like one using SHA-1, one using SHA-256, one using MD5 ...

The SKID is used to create the trust chain not based on the certificate subject and issuer but on the certificate SKID and authority key identifier (AKID). This makes it easier to deal with situations where the same subject string is used with multiple CA certificates. While the [RFC 3280 describes common ways to generate SKID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.2.1.2) the only real requirement is that the SKID of the CA certificate must match the AKID in all certificates issued by this CA.

In the example below it can be clearly seen that the SKID `BB:AF:7E:02:3D:FA:...` of the issuer matches the AKID of the issued certificate:

```
    ...
    Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    ...
    Subject: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
    ...
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:BB:AF:7E:02:3D:FA:A6:F1:3C:84:8E:AD:EE:38:98:EC:D9:32:32:D4

    ----

    ...
    Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    ...
    Subject: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    ...
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            BB:AF:7E:02:3D:FA:A6:F1:3C:84:8E:AD:EE:38:98:EC:D9:32:32:D4
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the SKI is calculated from the Subject and Public Key while the fingerprint is generated from the whole certificate.  If a certificate is renewed, its SKI will stay the same, while its fingerprint will change.

Comment: @garethTheRed SKI remains the same only when key pair is reused during renewal. If new key pair is generated, it will produce new SKI value.

Comment: @garethTheRed: the SKI __might__ be derived from subject and pubkey in specific (and likely many) implementations but it is not required to be done this way. From [RFC 3280 section 4.2.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3280#section-4.2.1.2): *"For CA certificates, subject key identifiers SHOULD be derived from the public key __or a method that generates unique values__."*. But of course SKI cannot be derived from the whole certificate since the SKI itself is part of the certificate.

Comment: @Crypt32 - that will be a re-key, not a renewal;  by RFC 3647 definition.  Although renewal is often used to describe both in practice.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Regardless of the specific method used to generate it, the same RFC also says that  _The subject key identifier extension provides a means of identifying certificates that contain a particular public key_.  Therefore, if for example, the _notAfter_ date changes the SKI should remain the same.

Comment: Thank you all @Steffen Ullrich So the bottom line is: it is ideally not only hash of the certificate's public-key, but a hash of the certificates' public-key and subject. I also need to add that I am asking for a leaf certificate not a CA. Am I right in my definition of subject-key-identifier?

Comment: @user9371654: the SKI is somehow related to the public key and can also be related to others (subject makes sense). It does not have to be a hash of these - it can also be some random as long as the same number is used for all certificates issued by this specific CA (and also renews of the CA using the same subject and key) and other CA certificates use different numbers. Of course, just using a hash of public key and subject would be a simple implementation which provides these properties. But it is not a requirement to implement it like this.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. If I am talking about a leaf certificate (e.g. for my domain: `myserver.com`) is the SKI a unique value for the subject `myserver.com` or is it a unique value to identify the CA who signed my leaf cert?

Comment: @user9371654: the SKI is a value specific to a certificate. The same SKI might be used in different certificates with the same public key and subject. I'm not aware of anything the SKI is actually used for in a leaf certificate and there is no requirement to have one there. The SKI in a CA certificate must match the AKI in the issued certificate.

Comment: “Where a key identifier has not been previously established, this specification RECOMMENDS [either the SHA-1 hash of `subjectPublicKey` or the four-bit value `0100` followed by the least significant 60 bits of the SHA-1 hash of `subjectPublicKey`] for generating `keyIdentifier`s[, though] a CA SHOULD use [a key's] previously established identifier.”